# How to solve multiple non-linear and independent equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I have 16 non-linear equations which are independent of each other i.e. they are not a system of equations. One way is to create 16 separate sub-routines and use fsolve to solve which i generally do.
But i need to reduce the number of sub-routines from 16 to one. Let me try to give an example of what i'm doing so far:

```
u01 = .001;....u016 = .001;
options=optimset('Display','notify','MaxFunEvals',10^7,'TolX',1e-,'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',10^5);
u1 = fsolve(@polsim1,u01,options);
        ..
        ..
u16 = fsolve(@polsim16,u016,options);
```

So, in the above example i have 16 subroutines i.e. polsim1-polsim16 where each includes 1 non-linear equation to solve for u's. This method is very cumbersome and messy. I need to do that in one subroutine. I believe i need to use index n = 1 to 16. But i'm not sure how to use it and where to use it.

Comment: @ m7913d  edited the question with the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your code to use vectors/cell arrays as follows:

```
% Write the initial point as a vector
u0(1) = .001;
        ..
u0(16) = .001;
% Write the equations as a cell array
polsim{1} = @polsim1;
        ..
polsim{16} = @polsim16;

options=optimset('Display','notify','MaxFunEvals',10^7,'TolX',1e-1,'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',10^5);
u = zeros(u0); % Allocate output space for efficiency
% loop over all the equations
for i=1:length(u0)
    u(i) = fzero(polsim{i},u0(i),options);
end
```

Note that I used `fzero` instead of `fsolve` to improve the efficiency, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018995/fastest-method-to-solve-multiple-nonlinear-independent-equations-in-matlab/45018996#45018996) for more information.

**Trick to automatically construct vector/cell array (Deprecated)**

For completeness, I should mention that you can initialise `u0` and `polsim` automatically using [`eval`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
for i=1:16
    eval(['u0(', num2str(i), ') = u0', num2str(i),';']);
    eval(['polsim{', num2str(i), '} = polsim', num2str(i),';']);
end
```

Note that I do not recommend this method. It is much better to directly define them as a vector/cell array.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an array of functions and initial guesses, as shown in the first example of the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) for `fsolve`.

```
% Array of equations, nx1 in size for n equations. 
% Ensure that the input (x) is indexed in each equation, e.g. x(1) in eqn 1
polsim = @(x) [x(1).^2 - 1
               2*x(2) + 3];

% Array of initial guesses, corresponding element-wise to eqn array 
u0 = [0.01; 0.01];

% Solver options
options = optimset('Display','notify','MaxFunEvals',10^7,'TolX',1e-5,'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',10^5);

% Solve
u = fsolve(F, u0, options);

>> u = [1.000; -1.500] % As expected for the equations in F and intial guesses
```

Comment: As the functions are independent, it may be more efficient to solve them separately.

Comment: Since the variables are kept independent (i.e. not using `x(1)` in equation 2) I don't see why it would necessarily slow down the solver doing it this way - there are still no dependencies? Would be interested if you could demonstrate there are performance advantages! This method just keeps things nice and clean :)

Comment: I performed the benchmark and created the following question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018995/fastest-method-to-solve-multiple-nonlinear-independent-equations-in-matlab/45018996#45018996. For 16 equations, both methods have almost the same efficiency (because I used `fzero` instead of `fsolve`)

Comment: Nice work putting that together @m7913d, looks like I'll stick to methods like I've written above, although nice tip about being able to explicitly set up `fsolve` to be independent. I wonder if @sayan might find your investigation useful. I also wonder if the benchmark equation is representative (no obvious reason why not) or if interesting things happen with more difficult equations.